How do i deploy TransparentUpgradeableProxy in frontend?
I deployed the logic/implementation contract now I want to deploy TransparentUpgradeableProxy that points to the logic/implementation contract
stack that I'm using Etherjs and VueJs

I tried to do this https://github.com/globe-and-citizen/cnc-portal/wiki/How-to-deploy-upgradeable-smart-contract-in-the-frontend but the read/view functions not working and got errors like in the picture, and the bytecode in deployed proxy only shows 0x, but all write/payable functions works well https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1260214060339957820/1260214060524245122/image.png?ex=668e814d&is=668d2fcd&hm=de632f4ae18f504b6b0c86e3f608c5f80062875fcdeffa3a62ed1fddd6406d34&=&format=webp&quality=lossless&width=2032&height=824
I tried to install hardhat in VueJS and got error packages fsevents

